# Getting low accuracy with deep convolutional NN trained on Imagenet 2011

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I've downloaded the Imagenet2011 dataset and tried to train the [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) imagenet network on it using the instructions [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html).  I used about 500K images for training and 70K images for validation.

I've also download the ILSVRC 2012 validation set for experiment.

Here are the results:

**On ILSVRC 2012 official validation set:**
My network: 46% accuracy, Original Caffe Imagenet network: 56% accuracy.

**On MY validation set:** My network: 53% accuracy, Original Caffe Imagenet network: 80% accuracy.

**On MY training data (checking for overfitting):** My network: 99% accuracy, Original Caffe Imagenet network: 70% accuracy.

I would like to ask for some help and tips regarding training:

1. I have the sense that my new network is overfitting. Do you agree? Should I use more images? use data augmentation to mechanically increase the size of the training set? or perhaps change the dropout parameter?
2. In the paper "Imagenet classification with deep convolutional neural networks" by Krizhevsky et al. [1](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/)  it says that the authors used 1.2M images for training and used data augmentation[2](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) that increases the size of the training data by a factor of 2048. However, no data augmentation (aside from random flips) is done in the code provided for the imagenet training. Is data augmentation not really required?
3. I'm only interested in about 100 classes from the ImageNet dataset. Say I was to train the imagenet network (from scratch) with only 100 classes with a total of 100K images. It's far less than the original 1.2M images, but It's also far less classes. Will the network overfit or will it give good performance on those 100 categories? Or should I use a different net architecture for only 100 classes? Would it be better to train the Imagenet network and then only fine tune using those 100 classes?
4. For the original 1K categories I only have 500K images (instead of 1.2M). Should I use categories with more images? How about using much more categories (and images)?

Thanks in advance!

Gil

[1](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) Krizhevsky, Alex, Ilya Sutskever, and Geoffrey E. Hinton. "Imagenet classification with deep convolutional neural networks." Advances in neural information processing systems. 2012.‏

[2](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) "The first form of data augmentation consists of generating image translations and horizontal reflections. We do this by extracting random 224 x224 patches (and their horizontal reflections) from the 256x 256 images and training our network on these extracted patches4. This increases the size of our training set by a factor of 2048, though the resulting training examples are, of course, highly interdependent."

Comment: you might get a better response if you post on the github page of caffe, its quite active. I think data augmentation and amount of training data is quite important - further, for each training set size, the optimal parameters of the deep net would be different, so default parameters would not be a good choice

Comment: Thank for you comment. I tried on Caffe's user group on Google groups, but got no response.

Comment: @GilLevi Hi, what was your approach to 100 class classification? I am also interested in only 10 classes however I am not able to achieve good accuracy with AlexNet type architecture.